# Dynamically setting the train-ability of tensorflow Variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a network with multiple scopes that contains multiple variables. I need a way to set the train-ability of a particular variable or a name scope such that they are not updated and not included in the gradient calculations and then set them to trainable after some condition. Is it even possible? If yes, How?

```
with tf.name_scope('layer1'):
     w = tf.Variable(...)
     b = tf.Variable(...)
     ... some function ...
with tf.name_scope('layer2'):
     w = tf.Variable(...)
     b = tf.Variable(...)
     ... some function ...
with tf.name_scope('layer3'):
     w = tf.Variable(...)
     b = tf.Variable(...)
     ... some function ...
```

I want to change the train-ability of variables in first scope because they are being restored from a pre-trained file and they are already learned. So, I want to train the variables in the other layers until they are learned and then set the train-ability of the variables in first scope back to True and train them together.

Comment: Text-only questions are rarely acceptable. Please show what you have done in code.

Comment: You can pass a `variable_list` to minimizer to decide which variable(s) to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could use is the var_list argument every optimizer has: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer

The documentation says:

> var_list: Optional list of Variable objects to update to minimize loss. Defaults to the list of variables collected in the graph under the key GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.

In your case you could say:

```
optimizer = GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
optimizer.minimize(loss,[w1,w2])
```

Let us know if this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to remove or add any variables from the var_list that is default to list of variables collected in the graph under the key GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES?

Comment: What you can do is create multiple optimizers, and select another one after a while...